# Azure Synapse Exception while reading table from synapse Dwh

Tags: pyspark, bigdata, azure-synapse

While reading from table I'm getting

> jdbc.SQLServerException : Create External Table As Sect statement failed as the path ####### could not be used for export.
> Error Code :105005

Comment: Please post an anonymised version of your code.  We do **not** need to see real table names or connection strings.  We **do** need to see the code you are running.

Answer (score 0):

> jdbc.SQLServerException : Create External Table As Sect statement
> failed as the path ####### could not be used for export. Error Code
> :105005

This error occurs because of  ***PolyBase*** can't complete the operation. The operation failure can be due to the following reasons :

- ***Network failure*** when you try to access the ***Azure blob storage***
- The configuration of the ***Azure storage account***.

You can fix this issue by following this [**article**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/analytics-platform-system/error-cetas-to-blob-storage#resolution) it helps you resolve the problem that occurs when you do a **`CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE AS SELECT`**.

For more in detail, please **refer** below links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/analytics-platform-system/error-cetas-to-blob-storage

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/access-external-data-from-azure-synapse-analytics-using-polybase

https://knowledge.informatica.com/s/article/000175628?language=en_US